# How can I get my coordinates in Minecraft pocket edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to use the /fill command, but I need my coordinates in order to use it. How can I get my coordinates in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Comment: I think this is a dupe, but I can't find the original

Comment: @Ben [You're talking about this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/289472/75275). The only problem is that the question _isn't_ a duplicate. The question was asking for [tag:minecraft], not [tag:minecraft-pocket-edition].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Without any behaviour packs:

As of 0.16.0, you can find your coordinates by enabling cheats and teleporting yourself nowhere.

```
/tp @p ~ ~ ~
```

In the console, it will display something like:

```
aytimothy teleported from 0, 0, 0 to 0, 0, 0
```

To sum it up, it'll display both your destination and your original co-ordinates. Since you're going nowhere, those two should be the same.

## With behaviour packs:

[This should do the trick](http://mcpedl.com/coordinates-unlocker-addon/).

You can do this by creating a `player_position_text` display in an `.mcmod` that changes the UI.